# Edge detection in noisy binary image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to clean the following image in order to perform edge and then polygon detection in order to extract the key buildings/features. Ideally I wish to end up with an image where the contours around houses and buildings are extracted correctly. The input image is [image: given here] (the full sized image is [given here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8h84qt4exqv68dz/Input.tif?dl=0))

Currently my processing has worked as follows:

1. Read in image and perform canny edge detection
2. Apply Gaussian and median blurs
3. Perform a probabilistic Hough transform
4. Draw the lines given from the Hough transform in red
5. Remove non-red lines, apply blurs to the red and perform contour detection

Which is done with the following code:

```
def read_tif(PATH):
    img = Image.open(PATH)

    # Turn into np array
    img = np.array(img, dtype=np.uint8)*255

    return img

# Read in image
img = read_tif(here("Images/" + params['img']))

dst = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 200, None, 3)

# Apply blurs
dst = cv2.GaussianBlur(dst, (5, 5), 0)
dst = cv2.medianBlur(dst, 3)

cdst = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cdstP = np.copy(cdst)

# Probabilistic Hough Transform
linesP = cv2.HoughLinesP(dst, 1, np.pi / 180, 50, None, 50, 10)

# Draw lines from Hough
if linesP is not None:
    for i in range(0, len(linesP)):
        l = linesP[i][0]
        cv2.line(cdstP , (l[0], l[1]), (l[2], l[3]), (0,0,255), 6, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

Unfortunately this method is not having too much success as although lines are detected well  there are many houses which are returned as several irregular polygons:
[image]

([see full image here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o526ipwgs8hs53w/Hough.jpg?dl=0)). I have tried playing around with various other methods like dilation (to increase the width of the house boundary lines) but these don't seem to improve results and amplify some of the noise in the image.

Any advice or help on methods/approaches that can help in improving these results is much appreciated, TIA!!

Comment: This is a line drawing. It has lines, not edges. Don’t apply an edge detection algorithm to an image that doesn’t have edges. You need a line detector.

Comment: Do you have any good recommendations for such detectors? I haven't had much luck with Hough transform...